# warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'p' used

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, local

This code compiles and runs though gives a Microsoft compiler error that I cant fix

warning C4700: uninitialized local variable '' used.

This is in the starting line of the code, I think

```
    void employee::loginemployee()
     {
     char uname[15];
     char pass[15];
      char p;
      int i=0;

cout<<"\n\t\tEnter User Name :-";
cin>>uname;

puts("\n\t\tEnter Password  :-");

while(p!=13)
{
    p=_getch();
    _putch('*');
    pass[i]=p;
    i++;
}

pass[i]='\0';

ifstream objdata;
objdata.open("HRStaff",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary|ios::app);

if(!objdata)
{
        cout<<"\n-----Cannot Open the File-----\n";
        //return 1;
}

int nflag=0;
while(!objdata.eof())
{
    objdata.read((char *)& info, sizeof(info));
    if(strcmp(uname,info.uname)==0 )
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t****************************************";
        cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\t\t Welcome TO EMS"<<info.uname<<endl;
        cout<<"\t\t****************************************\n"<<endl;
        info.putdata("SPS");
        cout<<"\n\tPress any key to log out...";
        nflag=1;
    }
}   

if(nflag==0)
{
    cout<<"\n\nSorry !! Your Username & Password do not match.";
    _getch();
    logoutAll();
}
```

objdata.close();
}

Answer (score 4):

The warning is quite clear. You declare a variable without initialising it:

```
char p;
```

then use its uninitialised value:

```
while(p!=13)
{
    // ...
}
```

Either initialise it before use:

```
char p = 0; // or any value other than 13
```

or restructure the logic so its value isn't used until you've assigned to it:

```
do
{
    // ...
} while (p != 13);
```

Then learn about *buffer overflow* and stop reading user input into fixed-sized buffers without checking the length. This is C++, not C, so you should usually use `std::string` to store string values.